# Start new chapter manually

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do I start a new chapter? I've been creating sections thinking that i was starting new chapters, but I just checked through variables and the chapter is the same for the whole document. How do InDesign know when to create a new chapter? Is there a "chapter break" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section exist within a document; each document is a chapter; sew a number of documents (chapters) together with a Book file; use a TOC which is driven by your Paragraph Styles to list and manage those documents in the book.

see these questions for further details:

[InDesign: chapters under sections in a multi-document book](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55274/indesign-chapters-under-sections-in-a-multi-document-book?rq=1)

[InDesign: How to make sure that new chapter are on the right side?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122784/indesign-how-to-make-sure-that-new-chapter-are-on-the-right-side?rq=1)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.. I was misunderstanding the "document' idea.